# A canvas into which I would like to load a Base64 string that represents a png image but just displays a blank white box

Tags: javascript, string, html, canvas, base64

I have a canvas into which I would like to load a Base64 string that represents a png image.  However, the following code just displays a blank white box and I am baffled as to why.  When I look at the data in the canvas, it looks identical to a canvas that gets its data from a FileReader object (also below).  Any help deducing this issue is greatly appreciated!

This code shows a white canvas:

html

```
        <canvas id="canvas" width="114" height="114" style="z-index: 999999; display: none; padding-left: 50px"></canvas>
```

javascript

```
        var websiteIconData = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_websiteIcon');
        if (websiteIconData.val() != '') {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            var loadedImg = new Image();
            loadedImg.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                Debugger.log(ctx);
            };
            loadedImg.src = websiteIconData.val();
            canvas.style.display = 'block';
        }
```

This code shows the image:

```
        $('#loadWebsiteIcon').on({
            change: function (ev) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    function draw() {
                        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
                        var img = new Image();
                        img.onload = function () {
                            var MAX_WIDTH = 114;
                            var MAX_HEIGHT = 114;
                            var width = img.width;
                            var height = img.height;
                            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                                width = MAX_WIDTH;
                            }
                            if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                            }
                            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                            for (var i = 0; i <= document.images.length; i++) {
                            }
                            Debugger.log(ctx);
                        };
                        img.src = e.target.result;
                    }
                    draw();
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(ev.target.files[0]);
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                canvas.style.display = 'block';
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
                $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_websiteIcon').val(imgData);
                Debugger.log(imgData);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I [tried to reproduce and **couldn't**](http://jsfiddle.net/FwCNn/), as you can see, a red dot appears. This makes me think that either `$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_websiteIcon').val();` isn't acting as you expect, or `var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();` isn't. `canvas.toDataURL` occasionally won't work if you have weird things happening with _origin_.

Comment: Yes, the issue is actually in the capturing of the image, the first code snippet actually does work if you put valid data into it. For some reason, the following code is not working:
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();                $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_websiteIcon').val(imgData);

Answer (score 1):

Be careful how Base64 is parsed. If it is parsed for email, it will insert a character ever 76 lines by default. Most Base64 encoders have an option to turn this off.  I am looking at [MIME::Base64](http://perldoc.perl.org/MIME/Base64.html)

From that document :

> The returned encoded string is broken into lines of no more than 76 characters each and it >will end with $eol unless it is empty.

where $eol was one of the arguments. In the case of this module, setting it to an empty string would prevent the base64 from being broken up.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue had little to do with the canvas API or the Base64 encoding.  It was more an issue of the canvas.toDataURL(); function getting called before the image had been loaded in the canvas.  Moving this line to within the img.onload function seemed to do the trick.  Below is the correct code:

```
    function initImageChange() {
//this is will be a string in Base64, in this case it is an <input type="text">... tag
        var imageData = $('#imageData');
//this is a canvas tag in on the page
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
//load the image from the imageData var if it exists
        if (imageData.val() != '') {
            var ctx2=canvas.getContext('2d');
            var loadedImg = new Image();
            loadedImg.onload = function() {
                ctx2.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
            };
            loadedImg.src = imageData.val();
            canvas.style.display = 'block';
        }
//this is a function that loads an image from a file onto the canvas and 
//sends the Base64 representation of this image to the text input tag.  This 
//could fairly easily be send directly to a post request or saved some other way
        $('#loadImage').on({
            change: function (ev) {
                var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
                var dataURL = '';
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    function draw() {
                        var img = new Image();
                        img.onload = function () {
                            var MAX_WIDTH = 130;
                            var MAX_HEIGHT = 110;
                            var width = img.width;
                            var height = img.height;
                            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                                width = MAX_WIDTH;
                            }
                            if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                            }
                            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                            dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
                            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_websiteIcon').val(dataURL);
                            ctx.restore();
                        };
                        img.src = e.target.result;

                    }
                    draw();
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(ev.target.files[0]);
                canvas.style.display = 'block';
            }
        });
    }
```